# No Cover under Album object

Tags: spotify

I'm making a prototype Spotify Application, and I am stuck on the last part of code.

I have a list of albums URI, and want to display an album with cover and link to it. So I parse the list, create an album object, and push the HTML corresponding to what I want.

It look like this:

```
for(var i = data.length; i--; ) {
  var cd = models.Album.fromURI(data[i].uri);
  var cover = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'player-image');
  cover.append($(document.createElement('a')).attr('href', data[i].uri));
  var img = new ui.SPImage(cd.cover ? cd.cover : "sp://import/img/placeholders/300-album.png");
  cover.children().append(img.node);
  $("#discs").append(cover);
}
```

I don't understand why `cd.cover` is always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the documentation is incorrect.  Instead of using the **cover** property use **image** from the **track** or **album** object.

Comment: Yes, it works ! Album oject has a image properties, but track object has a cover properties. (I had a solution get the first track of my album object and using the cover properties). It's proper with image properties of the album. Thx a lot !